# How to spawn a command block with a command inside and have a certain condition chain ect

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map type thing where you have to get through challenges to win a prize. The problem is that I need to spawn a command block stack, I know who to spawn a command block with a command but I also need to change it so that the command block is set to chain and always active. This is the current command I'm using,

```
/setblock -585.601 68.00000 -471.700 command_block 0 replace {Command:"/playsound block.piston.extend voice @p"}
```

Comment: This looks like an interesting concept I don't think I've seen before, I'd love to see if someone is able to answer this well.

Answer (score 3):

### 1.13+ answer

Blockstate numbers have been replaced by string blockstates. Also, nbt data is part of the block now. So for commandblocks you could place a block like this instead:

```
setblock <pos> chain_command_block[facing=up,conditional=true]{Command:"/playsound ...",auto:1b}
```

### Original answer

The things you are looking for are the blockstate (+8 if you want it to be conditional, as @Venya pointed out) and the chain command block, which goes by the name `chain_command_block` instead of a regular commandblock.
The other thing you're looking for is `{auto:1}`, the tag that makes the command always active.

So the complete command would be:

```
/setblock -585.601 68.0 -471.7 chain_command_block 8 replace {Command:"/playsound block.piston.extend voice @p",auto:1}
```

(I removed the unneccessary numbers from the coordinates as well)

Comment: Trying to figure this out to wow my kids!  I get an error saying it doesn't like the final curly-bracket.  Anyone able to replicate a currently workin version?  I'm on Java server 1.20.1

Comment: @JDMayfield the syntax has changed since the post was posted. I updated it with the current syntax.

Comment: I did get it to work late last night just by experimenting.  Figured it was a slight difference in syntax.   Thanks for the update though!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to test anything yet, but this should have everything you need

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block#ID

when I get a chance, I'll test it in 1.11

from a little bit of reading it seems like 0-5 are the six directions, and 8-14 are the directions with conditional mode `on`

note: the directions should be down, up, north, south, west, then east

Answer (score 0):

You need to put repeating_command_block instead of command_block for a repeating commandblock and chain_command_block instead of command_block for a chain one.